# awaitAll does not work in my test

Tags: scala, actor, future

When I create an *ad-hoc future* and call it it works ok.

```
scala> val f = future {Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 1); println("Hi"); 20}
f: scala.actors.Future[Int] = 

scala> f()
Hi
res39: Int = 20
```

When I create the same *future* and call `awaitAll` it does not work. The `awaitAll` returns `None` as if the future were not resolved.

```
scala> val f = future {Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 1); println("Hi"); 20}
f: scala.actors.Future[Int] = 

scala> awaitAll(1000 * 60 * 2, f)
Hi
res40: List[Option[Any]] = List(None)
```

Comment: the same problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305845/how-to-get-somex-from-the-results-of-futuresawaitall

Comment: @JCamphor Yes, probably. How would you suggest fix the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the `future` over `Future` which is deprecated.

How about: "Prefer the `Future` of the future in `scala.concurrent` to the `Future` of the past in `scala.actors`, which is deprecated."

As usual, Heather Miller says it best; see comment.

```
object Test extends App {
  import scala.concurrent._
  import Await._
  import Future._
  import duration._
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val data = List(1,2,3)
  result(traverse(data)(i => future{10 * i}), Duration("10 sec")) foreach println
}
```

Comment: "Prefer the future Future over deprecated."
Can we have that in plain English please?!

Answer (score 1):

I hope to help you.

```
import scala.actors._

object StackOverFlow13331294 extends App {
    Futures awaitAll (1000 * 60 * 1,
            Seq(new StackOverFlow13331294 !! "execute"): _*) foreach println
}

class StackOverFlow13331294 extends Actor {
    start
    override def act = react {
        case "execute" =>
            // Thread sleep 1000 * 60 * 1 ?
            println("Hi")
            reply("20")
    }
}
```